# Wiremock - How to have a request matching a word in the URL

Tags: java, regex, junit, mocking, wiremock

I have a URL similar to `https://localhost:8080/Test.dll?API=GetData&XML=<GetDataRequest><USERID='TEST1'><Address ID='0'><Address1>500</Address1><Address2>TestAddress2</Address2><City>TestCity</City><State>FL</State><Zipcode>89898</Zipcode></Address></GetDataRequest>`

How do I match the url against the string passed in "Zipcode" tags regardless of what is passed for other fields? In the above example, I want to match against "TestAddress2" data.

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming you have valid XML (when I try to test your XML in the `XML` query parameter, I get an invalid XML error), [you can use `matchingXPath` in the query parameters](https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#xpath) to match only when a certain value is met.

```js
{
  "request": {
    "urlPath": "/Test.dll",
    "queryParameters": {
      "XML": {
        "matchesXPath": {
          "expression": "/GetDataRequest/Address/Zipcode/text()",
          "equalTo": "89898"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200
  }
}
```